# Angular build command is not replacing environment files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using Angular v6.

My `angular.json` file has the following configuration

```
          "test": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "./src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "./src/environments/environment.test.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "serviceWorker": true
        },
```

When i run `ng build --configuration=test` it is not replacing the `environment.ts` file with `environment.test.ts` file.

Here is the configuration it added in the `main.js` file

```
/***/ "./src/environments/environment.ts":
/*!*****************************************!*\
  !*** ./src/environments/environment.ts ***!
  \*****************************************/
/*! exports provided: environment */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "environment", function() { return environment; });
var environment = {
    production: false,
    buildName: 'development',
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show your entire `angular.json` file?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: no. didn't find a solution. so as a work around, i put test env variables in environment.ts in a seperate branch and triggered build from there.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
npm run ng build -- --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the actual environment.ts file does not get replaced but if you look at the distribution files, the right values should be in there. You can test that it is doing this by opening main.js and looking for a particular variable name or value.

I myself keep the regular - environment.ts file blank so that if the app pulls up and doesn't throw errors then I know it did it properly.

To be clear, I don't like this small percentage of uncertainty and I'm not sure why it doesn't actually replace the file.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

for production build

```
ng build --prod
```

for test build

```
ng build
```

This will auto replace your urls as per command

Comment: I have 3 other configurations along with 'test'. so if i just run 'ng build' how will it know to pick the test env urls?

Comment: ng build with no params will grab the default configuration you have set.